# OpenMEAP hosted on Apache Tomcat Server via OpenShift Community

Tags: apache, tomcat, cloud, openshift

I'm preparing a development environment primarily for developing enterprise class cross-platform mobile hybrid apps and after much research I've decided to implement OpenMEAP on an Apache RedHat Cloud OpenShift container for advanced app management and services. The combination of these two could be interesting competition to commercial Mobile Enterprise Application Platforms.

I have my Eclipse setup properly to publish OpenMEAP to OpenShift Community Cloud and I can successfully create, build and deploy the OpenMEAP SLIC to Android devices and emulators after carefully following the instructions in these guides and videos:

[OpenMEAP Windows Installation Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFCZWbLeKlY)

[Get free Apache Tomcat Hosting in the Cloud for Java Applications at OpenShift Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brbOcoJ-4Ic)

I have only warnings in the Eclipse project. When I publish openmeap-admin-web and openmeap-services-web to the OpenShift container the WAR files are published but they don't expand and therefore cannot be accessed from the tomcat server over the web. If I could get past this problem I could proceed with actual development instead of the exhausting environment prep.

I know it's a long shot but is anyone attempting to use OpenMEAP with OpenShift (or any other cloud based Tomcat server)? I would also like to discuss OpenMEAP database requirements for an OpenShift (or Cloud) Apache Tomcat setup.

Any comment is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience onboarding OpenMEAD to OpenShift, but there are some things on the OpenShift Online community that you can review to see if it helps:
1) Troubleshooting with Logs:  https://www.openshift.com/faq/how-to-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-logs
2) Onboarding vanilla Tomcat:  https://www.openshift.com/blogs/free-apache-tomcat-hosting-in-the-cloud-for-java-applications-its-called-openshift

The later is onboarding Tomcat with a DIY cartridge.  What cartridges are you using?

Feel free to post to feedback to the OpenShift forums as well:  https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In addtion to OpenMEAP I've found two other open source Mobile Enterprise Application Platforms (OpenMobster and Convertigo.) I'll research the other two then determine which of the three to implement.

Comment: Thanks all! I decided to deploy the open source MEAP Convertigo on OpenShift or Azure Paas.  I have the Convertigo Community Server installed on an OpenShift gear running JBoss Server 7.1.  I just need to figure out how to configure database and settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy OpenMEAP on OpenShift from their [quickstart](https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/openmeap-on-openshift) page.

> Once you've created the quickstart, you'll need to add your authorization information to your Git repository. Making code changes will require you to set a public SSH key, and then to clone your new application Git repository onto your local machine. See the [Getting Started page](https://www.openshift.com/get-started#cli) for more steps in this flow.
>
> ### Step 1. Get Your Application UUID
>
> 1. Get your application uuid by going to the OpenShift Management Console and select the app name to copy the UUID or run this command: `rhc app show $appname | grep -i uuid`
> 2. Go to the administrative interface of the OpenMEAP instance: `https://$appname-$yournamespace.rhcloud.com/openmeap-admin-web/interface/`
> 3. Log in using the default credentials (userid/password): openshift/openmeap
> 4. From the **Main Menu**, navigate to **Settings**.
> 5. Under Global Settings & Preferences and Cluster Nodes set the following values:

```
 External Service URL: https://$appname-$yournamespace.rhcloud.com/openmeap-services-web
 File-system Storage Path Prefix: /var/lib/openshift/<application-uuid>/app-root/data
 Admin Server Accessible Service Url Prefix: https://$appname-$yournamespace.rhcloud.com/openmeap-services-web
 File-system Storage Path Prefix: /var/lib/openshift/<application-uuid>/app-root/data
```

> ### Step 2. Build Your Mobile Clients!
>
> Use: `openmeap.slic.appMgmtServiceUrl=https://$appname-$yournamespace.rhcloud.com/openmeap-services-web/application-management`
>
> More Information
>
> - For OpenMEAP developer resources visit http://wiki.openmeap.com
> - For more info on OpenMEAP in general visit http://www.openmeap.com
> - Uses jbossews-2.0 with code from https://github.com/OpenMEAP/openshift-openmeap-quickstart